# Laravel 5 : Is it possible to use __construct() and Illuminate\Http\Request for testcase classes?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying dependency injection for test cases, wondering if it is possible to do that for testing.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    protected $request;
    protected $user;

public function __construct(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $this->user    = $user;
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

This is how I usually do dependency injection.
For example, the following line gets an array instance of all the `user`s.

```
$users = $this->user->all();
```

I'd like to do the same thing for 'TestCase'. Here is an excerpt of the code.

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ViewTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $request;
    protected $user;

public function __construct(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $this->user    = $user;
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

This causes the following error.

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ViewTest::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in phar`

It sounds like that **`__construct()` must be an instance of `Request`**, but I don't understand what it actually means, since this code works in, let's say `controller` classes.

I've searched Laravel's documentation, but I'm not really sure if it's possible to do dependency injection for testing.

I'd appreciate if you would give any advice.

Comment: Are you trying to setup `Requet` and `User` to be used in testcase? or you trying to test a controller?

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. I'd like to use `Requet` and `User` by, for example. `$this->user->all()` in test cases.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with `TestCase` but one thing for sure you are passing `none` to the constructor. You can check how it been called.